# Path to NodeJs has not been specified in multi-device-hybrid apps

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

When i try to build a project i am getting an error message like Path to NodeJs has not been specified. File name is Microsoft.MDA.target.

How to specify node js path in it.

The error message is : "Path to NodeJs has not been specified. Please check that NodeJs has been installed and set the NodeJsDir environment variable before building."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have to add the nodejs installed location into your system path variable.

and the below link gives you pointer about, in general how to add into your environment

https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them